# animate in jquery not firing

Tags: jquery

my intention is to hide a div element as soon as the hide button is clicked. But the browser stays silent when i clicked the hide button.

Here is my code

```
 $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "slow", easing, callback);
    };

    $("#hid").click(function(){
        alert('here');
        $("#result").slideFadeToggle();
    });
```

hid is the id of the button which on clicked should actually hide the div. The alert inside the click funtction doesnt work either.

result is the id of the div to be hidden. any ideas?

Comment: works fine? http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/19/

Comment: it is not working here. i hav included the jquery libraries. i dunt hav a clue of wats wrong in this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The alert inside the click funtction doesnt work either.

That suggests that at the time you're doing your `$("#hid").click(...`, the element with the ID `hid` doesn't yet exist in the DOM. You can't access DOM elements until they're created.

Three ways to make sure they've been created before you try to access them are to use the jQuery [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, to simply ensure that your script code is loaded *after* the element in question, or to use jQuery's [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) feature.

So for instance, this will fail:

```
<html>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#hid").click(...);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='hid'>...</div>
...
```

But this will work (via a shortcut for `ready`):

```
<html>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#hid").click(...);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='hid'>...</div>
...
```

As will this (because the script is located *after* the element in the markup):

```
<html>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='hid'>...</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#hid").click(...);
</script>
...
```

...that latter being the way the Google team behind [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library) [recommend](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41); similarly, the [YUI team recommend](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) putting your scripts just before your closing `body` tag, which comes to the same thing.

And this will work (via `live`):

```
<html>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#hid").live('click', ...);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='hid'>...</div>
...
```

Comment: but the page is fully loaded and then only we are clicking the button right? by that time the dom tree should hav been loaded ?? correct me if i am wrong. i am not tht expertised

Comment: @CHID: It doesn't matter when you *click* the button. The element has to exist as of when you set up your click handler; otherwise, `$("#hid")` returns an empty jQuery object and there's nothing to hook up the handler on.

Comment: thank you very much crowder. the changes worked fine. got the problem and solved it

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works for me in chrome : [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/MbUbz/)

Do you import jquery before that code ?